# How to control system with 2 condersors+evaporators and 1 blower

Tags: wiring, hvac

I have problem with the control the HAVC system using 2 condensors + 2 evaporatora with one blower. 
I used 2 thermostats (4 wires/thermostat) to control. But the problem is when i turn on (cool position) each of thermostat, both condensors work.
Pls kindly advice me how to control each of them. 
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to set up a dual zone system, are there dampers involved?

Comment: What is the dampers @tester101? I just connected 02 thermostats to control 02 condensors. But there is 01 control board in blower. It had 04 wires: common - blower- heat- condensor- power (24v)
And there is 04 wires in each thermostat. I have tried to connected 02 wires to control each condensor. But they always work together. Not seperately

Comment: That seems to be an unusual configuration.  Typically in a multi-zone installation, there's a way to divert heating/cooling only to the zone calling for it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It sounds like you're not very familiar with HVAC system design, or implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual setup, it would help to know more about what you're trying to accomplish.

There are a few scenarios that I can imagine:

1. You've mis-wired something
2. Your thermostats have the Blower and Cool terminals connected together. -- In this scenario, when either Thermostat energizes the compressor and blower, then other compressor would also be energized through this shared connection.   You could use relays to isolate the blower (the thermostat energizes the relay, which in turn energizes the blower).  This doesn't seem likely, as that would preclude the use of a fan-only setting.
3. If your aim is to create a 2-stage system, where the second compressor kicks in if the first one isn't providing adequate cooling, you may be able to connect the power on the second thermostat to the compressor lead from the first thermostat, this would engage the second compressor only if the first is already engaged AND the second thermostat is calling for cool; in this case, the second thermostat would not need a connection to the blower as it would already be on from the first thermostat's call.